# How to override angular global styles with out using encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None or ::ng-deep?

Tags: angular, sass

I need to override global styles defined in the file src/styles.scss in a specific angular component.

I know that I can do it through  doing something like the following

`import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    ...
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})`

or by using  `::ng-deep`  or  `/deep/`   or  `>>>`  as required.

Both of these methods seem to have a draw back. The `ViewEncapsulation.None` method seems to make my overrided styles global and my architects are not convinced about using  `::ng-deep` either as they try to apply styles to elements by avoiding the scopes applied by the `ViewEncapsulation.Emulate`, I guess.

Can I be suggested with an alternative solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is a really good explanation of these at [hackernoon](https://hackernoon.com/the-new-angular-ng-deep-and-the-shadow-piercing-combinators-deep-and-drop-4b088dbe459). Unfortunately they are nearly all, if not already, deprecated.

I think what you need to be looking at is :host, which targets the current component's template that you are working on. This is of course, particular to that component only.

Comment: yeah i have been through that before posting the query. Guess the options are too limited in this case :(